# Android google map v2 is not working after the application is closed and reopened

Tags: android

When the application opens I create a new instance of a google map during onAttachedToWindow(), this works fine while the application is open. When I close the application and re-open it the google map does not load correctly, it just shows grey tiles.

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    if (hasCreated()) {
        uiGoogleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_content_map_fragment)).getMap();
    }
}
```

When should the google map be initialised to ensure it is loaded when the application is closed and re-opened?

EDIT:
I have tried initialising the map in onResume() and onCreate() and get the same problem

Comment: onAttachedWindow() is almost the last method getting called before showing the View. maybe you try it somewhere earlier on the lifecycle?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best place would be to create a class that extends `SupportMapFragment`, and initialise the map in:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity)
```

Besides that though, I think if you initialise the map in `onResume` of the container activity it should be ok.
 But if you by initialising you mean adding the mapfragment to the activity, I would suggest doing it in the xml or in your activity's `onCreate`. Just my two pennies.

Answer (score 0):

on Google API2 this hassle has been eliminated. 
What you need to do is just initialize the map you created on your xml.
`uiGoogleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_content_map_fragment))
                .getMap();`
So when you close and re-open it it will be available. no need to override anything.